# set.Age to java.lang.String

Tags: android

How can i convert the integer Age to string so that i can get the values on the text field

**Code**

```
   public void onSignUpClick(View v)
    {
        if (v.getId()==R.id.bregister);
        {
            EditText fname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fname);
            EditText lname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.lname);
            EditText age = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.age);
            EditText gender = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.gender);
            EditText uname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.uname);
            EditText pass1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass1);
            EditText pass2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass2);

            String fnamestr = fname.getText().toString();
            String lnamestr = lname.getText().toString();
            String agestr = age.getText().toString();
            String genderstr = gender.getText().toString();
            String unamestr = uname.getText().toString();
            String pass1str = pass1.getText().toString();
            String pass2str = pass2.getText().toString();

            if(!pass1str.equals(pass2str))
            {
                //popup message appears
                Toast pass = Toast.makeText(signup.this,"Password don't match!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                pass.show();
            }
            else
            {
                //insert the details in the database
            contact c = new contact();
            c.setFname(fnamestr);
            c.setLname(lnamestr);
            c.setAge(agestr);
            c.setGender(genderstr);
            c.setUname(unamestr);
            c.setPass(pass1str);
```

Comment: `String result = String.valueOf(intVar)` or `String result = intVar+"";`

Comment: @Piyush There is no `intVar`, everything is a String

Comment: Yeah ! I know . I have just provided a hint or suggestion  based on her question !

Comment: @Ayura you have got already in String format.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do

```
c.setAge(Integer.parseInt(agestr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert Int To String : `IntVar = Integer.parseInt(StringVar);`

Convert String to Int : `StringVar = String.valueOf(IntVar);`

in Your Source Code : `c.setAge(Integer.parseInt(agestr));`

Answer (score 0):

Use this

`string str = intVar + "";`

Now you can use str string variable to displah integer value and edit in edittext.

Alternate

`string str = String.valueOf(intVar);`